# javascript regex to check if a string is not all spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

What is the regex to check if a string is not all spaces (spaces = spacebar, tab etc.)? It's ok if there is at least one or more non space characters in string.

Example:

```
str = ''       // not allowed
str = '      ' // not allowed
str = '     d' // allowed
str = 'a    '  // allowed
str = '  d  '  // allowed
str = '  @s '  // allowed
```

I was trying this, but this seems to return true for everything...

```
str = '   a';
regex = /[\s]+/g;;
console.log(regex.test(str));
```

P.S I cannot use `trim` in here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is a test for `\S`, a non-space character:

```js
const isAllowed = str => /\S/.test(str);

console.log(
  isAllowed(''),
  isAllowed('    '),
  isAllowed('    d'),
  isAllowed('a    '),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

We could also use `trim()` here.  A string containing only whitespace would have a trimmed length of zero:

```js
var input = "   \t\t\t  \n";
if (input.trim().length == 0) {
    console.log("input has only whitespace");
}

input = "  Hello World!  \t\n ";
if (input.trim().length == 0) {
    console.log("input has only whitespace");
}
```